# sammyjs / knockoutjs routing - get id

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

If I am using a routing system like this

```
this.get('#home', function() {
          self.goHome(); 

    });

this.get('#products', function() {
        self.goProducts();
    });
    this.get('#products/list/:productID', function() {

      self.goProductsList(productID);

    });
```

how can I get the product ID from the url in sammy to use in knockout?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok worked it out

code is

```
self.goProductsList(this.params.productID);
```